# API for an ugly database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We have a pretty ugly legacy database at my workplace. Notice I am not in any way an expert with databases but some things just seem very weird. For example it's very common to see a table like below.

```
Zuser
  zuserid
  shoerdesc
  description
  virtualattributes
  birthdate1
  birthdate2
  qa_bookstoreid
```

We recently launched a "supposedly" REST API which acts as a dump of a few tables from the database. The end user ends up getting loads of fields with null values, data that is hard to interpret and a lot of junk.

API example:

```
{
  "last_updated" : "2010/10/10",
  "details" : {
    "zuserid"   : "b5b4546b3b33b",
    "birthday1" : "1980/10/10",
    "birthday2" : "1980/10/10",
    "zaccess"   : null,
    "zwebsite"  : null,
    ..
  }
}
```

In order to make the API work with the single client that actually uses it atm, we had to go through quite a bit of hand-holding, telling them what to show to the end user, etc.

**The good news** is that the upper level people expressed an interest in making the API more generic in the future and easier to use. I have since started looking already into good practices for this situation but my database experience is quite limited and I am not sure where to look. (I am mainly a software/web engineer.)

I have mainly been looking into the DataMapper pattern (we use ActiveRecord with Rails). It does seem like a lot of work and still I am unsure if it's best to do the mapping at the application level or create a new application that does the mapping in a new database and somehow sync the two.

Any ideas on what would be a good solution? Preferably something that will not break the existing database. Notice that I am quite low in the "corpochain" so most of decisions are made by others.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, any good REST api will need quite a bit of mapping to its domain model. Otherwise the API leaks the internal domain, or the internal domain ends up being modelled after the API - both approaches are far from ideal.

My suggestion is, separate your API completely from your domain model, in that way you can evolve either without impacting the other. Some people go a step forward and separate the domain model from the persistent entities (Robert C. Martin is strong advocate of this... even in Rails).

If you take this decision, then you can start thinking about *What is the API our clients want?* making it easy to use, consistent and relevant to your clients (as you mentioned, hand-holding is a symptom of an unclear API).